# Change ARM Mode to System Mode (CPSR) on ARMv8-A

Tags: assembly, arm, processor

I am using an ARM Cortex A53 (4-core) processor (ARMv8 architecture) in 32-bit mode. I need to use this instruction to enter system mode:

```
cpsid if, #0x1F
```

but this instruction, cps, makes my system crash. On the ARM1176JZF-S (ARMv6 architecture), this exact line worked flawlessly. I looked into it and it seems to have to do with a low privilege level, but svc instruction does not solve the issue as I thought it would. What do I need to do to accomplish system mode in this architecture?

Source for control bits:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344i/ch02s14s08.html

This is where I got CPS info from (in changing system modes):
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0527a/index.html

Comment: what chip is this and what mode are you in before you try this? (and execution level)

Comment: @old_timer SoC is BCM 2837. Working on Raspberry Pi 3 in Aarch32 mode. The exception level is not really known, but I was able to get the M bits [4:0] from the CPSR. Unfortunately, the output of those bits do not make any sense. The result was 0b00101, which does not correlate to any mode to my knowledge.

Comment: are you doing a boot without a config.txt?  and getting what you get?

Comment: @old_timer we are using config.txt, which looks like: "device_tree=" (not setting a value defaults to atags, which we are using). To my knowledge, nothing needs to be entered in config.txt relating to my issue, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: of course there is the question of why do you want to be in svc mode, hyp mode makes some things easier, but depends on what you are trying to do of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code to get out of hyp mode (assume no config.txt on the sd card) for both the pi2 and the pi3:

```
mrs r0,cpsr
bic r0,r0,#0x1F
orr r0,r0,#0x13
msr spsr_cxsf,r0
add r0,pc,#4
msr ELR_hyp,r0
eret
```

Lots of folks at the baremetal forum on the raspberry pi site, and there are variations on this theme.  Unlike the good old days you cant just change the cpsr once in HYP mode, but if you look at the eret instruction it accepts a new cpsr as well as branching (takes a new lr to feed to the pc) not really a return but a way to change the cpsr.  This is how the baremetal folks I know about are doing it.

There are of course assuptions required here to make this work and they happen to work with the pi.

If you have a config.txt then you need to be a little careful, the bootstrap code the GPU places for the arm "sorts" the cores and lets core 0 through as well as putting all of them in HYP mode.  (both pi2 and pi3), if you choose to defeat that:

```
kernel_old=1
disable_commandline_tags=1
```

then it is up to you to sort the cores

```
    mrs x0,mpidr_el1
    mov x1,#0xC1000000
    bic x1,x0,x1
    cbz x1,zero
not_zero:
    wfi
    b not_zero
zero:
```

so you dont have all four of them running the same code almost in parallel...

Comment: if you are just adding device tree stuff which may or may not be interesting for bare metal work, that just puts data at what offset 0x100 in arms address space, and you probably still boot at 0x8000, in 64 bit mode I think it is 0x80000 without a kernel_old=1.

Comment: this code puts you in svc mode on a pi2 and pi3 if I am confused and that is not what you are trying to do then please disregard.

Comment: also I run this code first thing in my program (branch over a vector table then do this first thing).  If you do the kernel_old thing then you start in svc mode but with the broadcom chip and/or the gpu starting the arm, you get all four cores coming out of reset at the same time.  If you dont do the kernel_old thing then for the last almost year the gpu bootloader has been putting the arm in hyp mode, so there you go you have to do one or the other to get into svc mode.

Comment: Thank you! Your code to get out of HYP mode worked. I was then able to change to system mode.

Comment: I assume you could change the orr r0,r0,#0x13 to go directly to system mode instead of svc mode as that is what that line is doing.

Comment: I had thought that supervisor mode was an intermediate step to get into system mode, so I kept your code the same and then after the eret, I could use the instruction 'cpsid   if, #0x1F' for system mode. Works like a charm. I can try orring with 0x1F like you mentioned, but I don't think this would have the same effect as I need the "id" and "if" part of cps instruction.

Comment: no not necessarily orring with 0x1F but orring with whatever the system mode bit pattern is...

Comment: duh, okay system mode is 0x1F...and you dont need the bic then just orr in 0x1F...

Comment: Ah, nice. So just orring there will accomplish the same instruction as cpsid if?

Comment: no the bic instruction above using 0x1F makes the lower 5 bits a zero, then the orr of 0x13 makes the lower 5 bits 0x13.  But if you want to set all five lower bits you dont need to clear them first you dont need the bic 0x1F you can just orr 0x1f and set all of them...

Comment: I have a question regarding multicore since you seem knowledgeable about its CPU. In setting up the cores with your method, the MPIDR prints out the following: 10000000000000000000000000000000 which, according to this: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388e/CIHEBGFG.html the last 2 bits mean signify it is running on core 0 and recognizes that is has a cluster of cores. I want to implement multicore scheduling and am testing simply running on a core other than 0 (better yet, accessing all four). Any direction you can put me in?

Comment: where it hits the non_zero or as you already know looking at the bits in the mpidr you can send the other cores to some other code space.  I think how the pi folks do it is use what I would call and I think they call mailboxes, but could just be any memory location, create an address based on the mpidr, say for example core 1 would get 0x10004, core 2 0x10008, core 3 0x1000C you can do this mathmatically and dont need an if core1 then.  write a zero to that address, then go into an infinite loop reading that address, when it changes branch to that address.

Comment: In 64 bit mode they appear to have a wfe in the loop so it doesnt burn cycles constantly, I dont remember seeing that in the 32 bit mode, but they could have added it since I looked last.  Basically in short just park the other three cores in a place where they are waiting for core0 to ask them to do work then ask them to do work in turn.  This way core0 can setup the system and the scheduler and almost everything else then you can release each of the other cores into this system you have prepared.  they may need individual setup but naturally you send them there first.

Comment: you could certainly do this in multiple steps core0 preps a little, asks core1 to prep itself waits for a shared location to say that it is done, park core1 repeat with the others, do more prep then release them into the scheduler and/or operating system.

Comment: if there were reset controls my personal preference would be keep them in reset until I am ready to use them.  I dont at the moment know if that is possible on this platform.